# Memory-optimal base64 encoding Java library

Tags: java

Is there any trust-worthy library in Java that

- encodes a byte array to base64 without using intermediate structures, where you provide the output byte array as well as an offset for that output array (from where to start writing out the base64)
- can return the base64 byte length for a given input byte array without memory consumption

I need this to be able to encode a byte array without using any excess memory whatsoever. I wrote my own code for this but I was asked to use a library instead because of how important that part of the code is.

The [library found here or the libraries it references](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) (including the default Base64 lib in Java 8) provide no such services. The best there is is a library that allows you to specify the output array, but no offset.

Comment: For the actual de-/encoding Guava may be suitable using `BaseEncoding.encodingSink(...)` it does not directly work on byte arrays but the sinks could be used to implement something similar. But adding Guava just for efficient Base64 decoding is a bit oversized IMHO.

Comment: Why is SO important to fine control the memory usage. Unless we're talking about gigabyte-sized data on not-so-powerful hardware, it's unlikely that a base64 conversion would be the botleneck here.

Comment: @Alejandro You certainly have a point, it's to avoid OOMErrors as much as possible for a service that converts a few files to base64 format and puts them in XML structures which are sent through to other services. The service is running on K8s with limited resources. I tried to go the whole way and minimize memory consumption as much as possible.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, might use it since other parts of our code can benefit from using Guava.